# AWK multiple search pattern with state machine condition

Tags: bash, awk

I have been trying to get this condition working, but getting syntax with awk.

The text file is below:

```
---- Test# 1 ----
#------ iteration 1 -------
# line 1
# line 2
# line 3
#------- iteration 2 ------
# line 1
# line 2
#------- iteration 3 ------
#------- iteration 4 ------
# line 1
# line 2
**************************
---- Test# 2 ----
#------ iteration 1 -------
#------- iteration 2 ------
# line 1
# line 2
# line 3
# line 4
# line 5
#------- iteration 3 ------
#------- iteration 4 ------
# line 1
# line 2
# line 3
**************************

....
....

---- Test# 30 ----
#------ iteration 1 -------
# line 1
# line 10
#------- iteration 2 ------
# line 1
# line 2
#------- iteration 3 ------
# line 1
# line 2
# line 3
# line 4
#------- iteration 4 ------
# line 1
# line 2
# line 3
**************************
```

I am interested to filter results based on Test# and then the iterations.

Essentially expected result:

```
TestCase # 1
Iteration1 # Total lines 3
Iteration2 # Total lines 2
Iteration3 # Total lines 0
Iteration4 # Total lines 2

TestCase # 2
Iteration1 # Total lines 0
Iteration2 # Total lines 5
Iteration3 # Total lines 0
Iteration4 # Total lines 3

...

TestCase # 30
Iteration1 # Total lines 2
Iteration2 # Total lines 2
Iteration3 # Total lines 4
Iteration4 # Total lines 3
```

I have done the following:

```
awk '/iteration 1\s/{flag = 1} \iteration 2\s/ {flag =0}; f{print $0}' test.txt
```

This results sets the flag to 1 when iteration 1 is matched and then sets flag to 0 when iteration 2 is found. Also, anytime f is true, it prints the line. This is pretty simple, however, when I try to include additional search pattern under f, that's when I get the syntax.

For example:

```
awk '/iteration 1\s/{flag = 1} \iteration 2\s/ {flag =0}; f{/Test# 1$/{print $0}}' test.txt
```

Gives me syntax error on `/{print $0}`.

Once I have the basic structure up, I need to do a for loop to just go over the whole file and generate expected data.

Comment: try `f{ if ($0 ~ /Test# 1$/) {print $0}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
function print_count() {
    if (iteration)                              # if iteration > 0 then ...
       printf "Iteration%s # Total lines %s\n", iteration, linecnt

    iteration = linecnt = 0                     # reset variables
}

NF==0             { next }                      # skip blank lines
/^[*]{10}/        { print_count()               # if line starts with (at least) 10 astericks then flush previous iteration count
                    next
                  }
$2 == "Test#"     { if (NR>1)
                       print ""                 # print blank line between Test blocks
                    print "TestCase #",$3
                    next
                  }
$2 == "iteration" { print_count()               # flush previous iteration count
                    iteration = $3
                    next
                  }
iteration         { linecnt++ }
END               { print_count() }             # flush last iteration count
' test.txt
```

This generates:

```
TestCase # 1
Iteration1 # Total lines 3
Iteration2 # Total lines 2
Iteration3 # Total lines 0
Iteration4 # Total lines 2

TestCase # 2
Iteration1 # Total lines 0
Iteration2 # Total lines 5
Iteration3 # Total lines 0
Iteration4 # Total lines 3

TestCase # 30
Iteration1 # Total lines 2
Iteration2 # Total lines 2
Iteration3 # Total lines 4
Iteration4 # Total lines 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
awk '
/^----/{sub(/^[ \t-]+/,""); sub(/[ \t-]+$/,""); section=$0; next} 
/^[#]----/{sub(/^[# \t-]+/,""); sub(/[# \t-]+$/,""); subsec=$0; cnt[subsec]=0; next}
/^[*]+$/{
    print section
    for (e in cnt) {
        printf "%s # Total lines: %s\n", e, cnt[e]
    }
    print ""
    split("",cnt)
}
{cnt[subsec]++}
' file
```

Or with Ruby:

```
ruby -e '
$<.read.scan(/^-{3,}\s(.*?) -{3,}$\R([\s\S]*?)(?=^[*]+$)/).
    each{|tst,result|
        puts tst
        result.scan(/^#-{4,} (.*?) -{3,}$\R([\s\S]*?)(?=^#-)/).each{|i,ss|
            puts "#{i} # Total lines: #{ss.split(/\R/).length}"
        }
}
' file
```

Either prints:

```
Test# 1
iteration 1 # Total lines: 3
iteration 2 # Total lines: 2
iteration 3 # Total lines: 0
iteration 4 # Total lines: 2

Test# 2
iteration 1 # Total lines: 0
iteration 2 # Total lines: 5
iteration 3 # Total lines: 0
iteration 4 # Total lines: 3

Test# 30
iteration 1 # Total lines: 2
iteration 2 # Total lines: 2
iteration 3 # Total lines: 4
iteration 4 # Total lines: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

An example of using a multidimensional array in GNU awk:

```
awk '
/^--/{idx1++; idx2=0}
/^#-/{idx2++; arr[idx1][idx2]=0}
/^# /{arr[idx1][idx2]++}
END{
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"
    for(i in arr){
        if(i!=1) print ""
        print "TestCase # " i 
        for(j in arr[i])
            print "Iteration" j " # Total lines " arr[i][j]
    }   
}' file
```

Comment: Nice! The construct `[x][y]` is GNU only.

Comment: @dawg : this approach guarantees neither the sequentiality nor even the monotonicity of the output. Illustrated example below

Comment: @RARE Kpop Manifesto:
Thanks for pointing out. I think the following should be added before the for loop of the End routine.
PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"

Comment: `@dam` : perfect - that's all u need

Answer (score 0):

`@dam/@dawg` : perfectly pre-sorted input doesn't automatically result in perfectly sorted output

```
# 2  | 1     | 9
# 5  | 1     | 8
# 5  | 3     | 444
# 5  | 22    | 291
#38  | 9     | 0
#38  | 13    | 6
#38  | 70    | 2
```

---

```
gawk -F= '{ ___[$++_][$(_+_--)] = $NF } END { OFS = "\t | "

            for (_ in ___) { 
              for (__ in ___[_]) { 
                print _ ,__, ___[_][__] } } } '
```

---

```
# 5  | 1     | 8
# 5  | 3     | 444
# 5  | 22    | 291
#38  | 9     | 0
#38  | 13    | 6
#38  | 70    | 2
# 2  | 1     | 9
```

---

Answer (score -1):

why are people using loops and arrays ?

---

```
    # gawk profile, created Sat Apr 29 12:11:32 2023

    # Rule(s)

   44  (__ = substr( $(_ = _<_), ++_, ++_)) < "##" ? !++____ : \
      $!NF = __ == "--" ? $(_ + (___ = !_)) "\n" \
                        : sprintf("%.*s%.*s%.*s",((_^=_+=_)^!_< ++___)*_,
                                         (+____) "\n",  (__ != "**") * _, 
                         "Iteration "(___)"# Total lines ", !_,____ = !_)
```

---

```
Test# 1
Iteration 1 # Total lines 3
Iteration 2 # Total lines 2
Iteration 3 # Total lines 0
Iteration 4 # Total lines 2
Test# 2
Iteration 1 # Total lines 0
Iteration 2 # Total lines 5
Iteration 3 # Total lines 0
Iteration 4 # Total lines 3
Test# 30
Iteration 1 # Total lines 2
Iteration 2 # Total lines 2
Iteration 3 # Total lines 4
Iteration 4 # Total lines 3
```